# Role of xor in ARX construction

Tags: arx

In ARX construction like Salsa 20, why xor operation is required? That is why AR is not sufficient? Note that xor is a linear operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xor is the "addition" operator for algebra with boolean operators, while AND is the "multiplication" operator for boolean operators. "Regular" addition and multiplication are the addition/multiplication operators for integers. So speaking of "linearity" in the sense of algebraic compatibility, XOR and integer addition are non-linear. I feel like this [question/answer(s)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12634/reason-why-xor-is-a-linear-operation-but-ordinary-addition-isn-t) sums it up pretty well.

As for why xor is required/why AR is not sufficient, technically, AR is equivalent to ARX, but less efficient. See the paper [Rotational Cryptanalysis of ARX](https://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2010/61470339/61470339.pdf) . There are some details to it:

> We also show that the
>   AR systems
>   , that do not use XOR, are theoretically
>   equivalent to ARX systems. However, we prove that they are less secure with
>   the same number of operations, because of the linear mod 2**n approximation.
>   It is also easy to prove that omitting addition or rotation is devastating, and
>   such systems (XR and AX) can always be broken.

Comment: "Xor is a linear operation with respect to AND" Are you sure? AND+ROT+XOR are certainly sufficient for constructing secure ARX-like ciphers as an example compare NORX with ChaCha. But since I'm not sure about how linearity is defined in this context, you might still be right.

Comment: Also, the quote says that AR is sufficient, just less efficient than ARX.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I meant linearity as in algebraic compatibility, if that makes any sense? I updated my answer to hopefully clarify what I meant. NORX uses a half-adder like function if I recall correctly, which would imply that while it is implemented in XOR+ROT+AND, it is still basically performing integer addition.