# MD5 Algorithm is nonlinear?

Tags: md5

https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/978/1/012116/pdf

> Each operation performs a nonlinear function on three of a, b, c,and d.

```
      F(X,Y,Z) = XY v not(X) Z
      G(X,Y,Z) = XZ v Y not(Z)
      H(X,Y,Z) = X xor Y xor Z
      I(X,Y,Z) = Y xor (X v not(Z))
```

So MD5 Algorithm is nonlinear?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. Do you know what is linear and non-linear? What operations can be linear? And, do you know what will happen a linear cryptographic algorithm?

Comment: I think y=x is linear and y = x^2 is non-linear,a linear cryptographc algorithm can not be hash algorithm,I don't know what operations can be linear.

Comment: Usually a function $f$ is linear if $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$. This is not a desirable property of any cryptographic hash function.

Comment: if a hash function was linear, would it be useful?

Comment: A linear hash function could have an easy collision and pre-images.

Comment: Start here [Reason why “XOR” is a linear operation, but ordinary “addition” isn’t?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/12634/18298) and follow the links on the right; ARX.